# How to cache images using a cache key filter?

Tags: caching, download, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I know that MvvmCross allows us to download and cache images into our applications by using both [DownloadCache](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#downloadcache) and File plugins. But is it possible to setup the default cache configuration to use a custom cache key filter?

Reference:

> Sometime, you may not want to use the image URL as cache key because
>   part of the URL is dynamic (i.e.: for access control purpose)

[SDWebImage - Using cache key filter](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#using-cache-key-filter)

Did some of you already developed this feature?

I am new to MvvmCross and I couldn't find the open source implementation for the `IMvxImageHelper<Bitmap>` interface. As my application always download images using a temporary signature at the end of each image url, the cache mechanism never works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the DownloadCache plugin in MvvmCross doesn't support that CacheKey filter - it caches on url.

The existing source is in Plugins/Cirrious/DownloadCache in http://github.com/slodge/mvvmcross

Alternatively `IMvxImageHelper<UIImage>` is a very simple interface so you could create your own custom implementation - especially as it sounds like you have a clear understanding of what you need.